# chart.js load totally new data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[The API for `chart.js`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart) allows one to edit points of the datasets loaded into it, for example:

> #### `.update( )`
>
> Calling update() on your Chart instance will re-render the chart with
>   any updated values, allowing you to edit the value of multiple
>   existing points, then render those in one animated render loop.
>
> #### `.addData( valuesArray, label )`
>
> Calling addData(valuesArray, label) on your Chart instance passing an
>   array of values for each dataset, along with a label for those points.
>
> #### `.removeData( )`
>
> Calling removeData() on your Chart instance will remove the first
>   value for all datasets on the chart.

All of these are great, but I cannot figure out how to load an entirely new dataset in, wiping out the old. The documentation does not seem to cover this.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I had huge problems with this

First I tried `.clear()` then I tried `.destroy()` and I tried setting my chart reference to null

What finally fixed the issue for me: deleting the `<canvas>` element and then reappending a new `<canvas>` to the parent container

---

There's a million ways to do this:

```
var resetCanvas = function () {
  $('#results-graph').remove(); // this is my <canvas> element
  $('#graph-container').append('<canvas id="results-graph"><canvas>');
  canvas = document.querySelector('#results-graph'); // why use jQuery?
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = $('#graph').width(); // resize to parent width
  ctx.canvas.height = $('#graph').height(); // resize to parent height

  var x = canvas.width/2;
  var y = canvas.height/2;
  ctx.font = '10pt Verdana';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText('This text is centered on the canvas', x, y);
};
```

Comment: This answer works, but I found destroy also works in the latest version. Recommended on this post - https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/559

Comment: it would help the empty the graph-container div to remove old iframes
$('#results-graph').remove(); 
$('#graph-container').empty();
$('#graph-container').append('<canvas id="results-graph"><canvas>');

Answer (score 81):

You need to destroy:

```
myLineChart.destroy();
```

Then re-initialize the chart:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChartLine").getContext("2d");
myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Comment: just use it like this    if(window.myLine){
     window.myLine.destroy();
    
}  OR    if(myLineChart){
    myLineChart.destroy();
    
}

Comment: Can confirm destroying then re-initialising doesn't cause any flickering and looks like the data points were dynamically updated

Answer (score 52):

With Chart.js V2.0 you can to do the following:

```
websiteChart.config.data = some_new_data;
websiteChart.update();
```

Comment: Exactly what the op asked for.

Comment: When I do `chart.config.data = newData`, I have this error:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.data.datasets.length')`

Someone have the same issue?

Answer (score 27):

It is an old thread, but in the current version (as of 1-feb-2017), it easy to replace datasets plotted on chart.js:

suppose your new x-axis values are in array x and y-axis values are in array y,
you can use below code to update the chart.

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = [1,1,1];

chart.data.datasets[0].data = y;
chart.data.labels = x;

chart.update();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Man! Wasted all day. Finally stumbled upon your answer. Thank you.

Comment: This was helpful and worked for me. Even just using [] to set an empty dataset, and then doing a new "push" will do the trick as well.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I found this answer useful. It works for me!

Answer (score 18):

ChartJS 2.6 supports data reference replacement (see [Note](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig) in update(config) documentation). So when you have your Chart, you could basically just do this:

```
myChart.data.labels = ['1am', '2am', '3am', '4am'];
myChart.data.datasets[0].data = [0, 12, 35, 36];
myChart.update();
```

It doesn't do the animation you'd get from adding points, but existing points on the graph will be animated.

Answer (score 12):

My solution to this is pretty simple. (VERSION 1.X)

```
getDataSet:function(valuesArr1,valuesArr2){
        var dataset = [];
        var arr1 = {
            label: " (myvalues1)",
            fillColor: "rgba(0, 138, 212,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(0, 138, 212,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: valuesArr1
        };
        var arr2 = {
            label: " (myvalues2)",
            fillColor: "rgba(255, 174, 087,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(255, 174, 087,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: valuesArr2
        };
        /*Example conditions*/
        if(condition 1)
          dataset.push(arr1);
        }
        if(condition 2){
          dataset.push(arr1);
          dataset.push(arr2);
        }

        return dataset;
    }

var data = {
    labels: mylabelone,
    datasets: getDataSet()
};
if(myBarChart != null) // i initialize myBarChart var with null
    myBarChart.destroy(); // if not null call destroy
    myBarChart = new Chart(ctxmini).Bar(data, options);//render it again ...
```

No flickering or problems. `getDataSet` is a function to control what dataset I need to present

Comment: Can you add the code snippet of getDataSet() as well?

Comment: Added the getDataSet() example

Answer (score 8):

I answered this here see [How to clear a chart from a canvas so that hover events cannot be triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815851/how-do-clear-a-chart-from-a-canvas-so-that-hover-events-cannot-be-triggered/30468773#30468773)

But here is the solution:

```
var myPieChart=null;

function drawChart(objChart,data){
    if(myPieChart!=null){
        myPieChart.destroy();
    }
    // Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
    var ctx = objChart.getContext("2d");
    myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, {animateScale: true});
}
```

Answer (score 6):

According to docs, `clear()` clears the canvas. Think of it as the Eraser tool in Paint. It has nothing to do with the data currently loaded in the chart instance.

Destroying the instance and creating a new one is wasteful. Instead, use API methods `removeData()` and `addData()`. These will add/remove a single segment to/from the chart instance. So if you want to load completely new data, just loop a chart data array, and call `removeData(index)` (array indexes should correspond to current segment indexes). Then, use `addData(index)` to fill it with the new data. I suggest wrapping the two methods for looping the data, as they expect a single segment index. I use `resetChart` and `updateChart`. **Before continuing, make sure you check `Chart.js` latest version and documentation. They may have added new methods for replacing the data completely**.

Comment: I like your answer and its consistent with the information I have been reading online. If you are able to show and example that would be really helpful. The two examples that I have seen online that are similar are: http://jsbin.com/yitep/5/edit?html,js,output and http://jsbin.com/yitep/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The only problem is that updating a chart becomes extremely cumbersome and super slow if you have to replace the chart data with essentially a completely different dataset. For starters, I have not found a way to update existing x-axis *labels*. Destroying and reinstantiating the entire chart is the only real solution in such circumstances.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only dealt with a Doughnut chart, which is less complex. Did you check out the latest API?

Answer (score 5):

None of the above answers helped my particular situation in a very clean way with minimal code. I needed to remove all datasets and then loop to add in several datasets dynamically. So this snipped is for those that make it all the way to the bottom of the page without finding their answer :)

Note: make sure to call chart.update() once you have loaded all of your new data into the dataset object. Hope this helps somebody

```
function removeData(chart) {
   chart.data.datasets.length = 0;
}

function addData(chart, data) {
  chart.data.datasets.push(data);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not is necesary destroy the chart. Try with this

```
function removeData(chart) {

        let total = chart.data.labels.length;

        while (total >= 0) {
            chart.data.labels.pop();
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.pop();
            total--;
        }

        chart.update();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue, I have 6 pie charts on a page which can all be updated at the same time.  I am using the following function to reset chart data.

```js
// sets chart segment data for previously rendered charts
function _resetChartData(chart, new_segments) {
    // remove all the segments
    while (chart.segments.length) {
        chart.removeData();
    };

    // add the new data fresh
    new_segments.forEach (function (segment, index) {
        chart.addData(segment, index);
    });
};

// when I want to reset my data I call
_resetChartData(some_chart, new_data_segments);
some_chart.update();
```

Comment: While this works, I found that it’s *much slower* (due to animation when adding each point) compared to recreating chart altogether.

Answer (score 4):

I tried [neaumusic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25064022/227821) solution, but later found out that the [only problem with destroy is the scope](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/559#issuecomment-111695552).

```
var chart;

function renderGraph() {
    // Destroy old graph
    if (chart) {
        chart.destroy();
    }

    // Render chart
    chart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById(idChartMainWrapperCanvas),
        chartOptions
    );
}
```

Moving my chart variable outside the function scope, got it working for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Please Learn how Chart.js (version 2 here) works and do it for whatever attribute you want:**

---

1.Please suppose you have a bar chart like the below in your HTML:

```
<canvas id="your-chart-id" height="your-height" width="your-width"></canvas>
```

2.Please suppose you have a javascript code that fills your chart first time (for example when page is loaded):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('your-chart-id').getContext('2d');
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: your-lables-array,
        datasets: [{
            data: your-data-array,
            /*you can create random colors dynamically by ColorHash library [https://github.com/zenozeng/color-hash]*/
            backgroundColor: your-lables-array.map(function (item) {
                return colorHash.hex(item);
            })
        }]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [ { ticks: {beginAtZero: true} } ]
        },
        title: {display: true, fontSize: 16, text: 'chart title'},
        legend: {display: false}
    }
});
```

Please suppose you want to update fully your dataset.
It is very simple. Please look at the above code and see how is the path from your chart variable to data and then follow the below path:

- select `chartInstance` var.
- Then select `data node` inside the `chartInstance`.
- Then select `datasets node` inside the `data node`.
  (note: As
  you can see, the `datasets node` is an array. so you have to
  specify which element of this array you want. here we have only one
  element in the `datasets node`. so we use `datasets[0]`
- So select `datasets[0]`
- Then select `data node` inside in the `datasets[0]`.

This steps gives you `chartInstance.data.datasets[0].data` and you can set new data and update the chart:

```
chartInstance.data.datasets[0].data = NEW-your-data-array
//finally update chart var:
chartInstance.update();
```

---

**Note:**
By following the above algorithm, you can simply achieve to **each node you want**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clean old data.  No need to re initialize:

```
for (i in myChartLine.datasets[0].points)
    myChartLine.removeData();
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for how to do this in React. For a linechart, assuming you have a wrapper component around the chart:

(This assumes you are using v2. You do not need to use `react-chartjs`. This is using the normal `chart.js` package from npm.)

```
propTypes: {
  data: React.PropTypes.shape({
    datasets: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
      React.PropTypes.shape({

      })
    ),
    labels: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  }).isRequired
},
componentDidMount () {
  let chartCanvas = this.refs.chart;

  let myChart = new Chart(chartCanvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: this.props.data,
    options: {
      ...
    }
  });

  this.setState({chart: myChart});
},
componentDidUpdate () {
    let chart = this.state.chart;
    let data = this.props.data;

    data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => chart.data.datasets[i].data = dataset.data);

    chart.data.labels = data.labels;
    chart.update();
},
render () {
  return (
    <canvas ref={'chart'} height={'400'} width={'600'}></canvas>
  );
}
```

The `componentDidUpdate` functionality allows you to update, add, or remove any data from the `this.props.data`.

Answer (score 2):

**To keep the chart size from changing after reloading:**

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false
```

**To clear the previous chart:**

```
myChart.destroy();
```

**For example:**

HTML:

```
<canvas id="ChartJs" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var myChart = null;
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: DATA,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
};

if (myChart != null) 
    myChart.destroy();
myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('MyChart ').getContext('2d'), config);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pavan gave the right answer; but I would like to expound upon that a bit. This issue plagued me FOREVER when I first got started using ChartJS.

Calling the `.update()` function on your Chart object is correct. No need to delete the existing chart or do something like removing the canvas element to later append a new one. That works.. but isn't necessary.

**Working CodePen:** https://codepen.io/vpolston/pen/KKRoEBY

**Video walkthrough:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ac5pzmHO3_A

Firstly if you want to know the *why* then I would recommend doing a `console.log(myChart)` of your chart object. You'll see all kinds of properties that can be updated by simply assigning it a new value and then calling the `myChart.update()` on your chart.

Let's say you have a chart that you called myChart when you instantiated it.. this part:

`const myChart = new Chart('myChart', {}`

The variable name is important. To update the dataset you silo down into what you saw when you console.log'd the chart. So your dataset would be

```
myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data
```

Just assign that a new value like this:

```
const newDatasArray = [1,52,23,23,48];
myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = newDatasArray;
```

and then for the labels if you needed to change those:

```
const newLabelsArray = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"];
myChart.config.data.labels = newLabelsArray;
```

And then finally call the update function with `myChart.update();`

You'll see the chart update to use the new dataset and/or labels.

**Hopefully that gives a bit more insight into properly updating a chart. If you have a further question let me know and I'd be glad to try to help.**

Thanks,
VP

Comment: This is the only solution here that helped me, thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can find so far for myself is to re-initialize the chart from scratch:

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

However this seems a bit hokey to me. Any better, more standard solution anybody?

Comment: This pretty much works for me except you need to first do myLineChart.destroy() to get rid of the old one or you'll have a flicker as it redraws.

Answer (score 0):

I had loads of trouble with this too. I have data and labels in separate arrays then I reinitialise the chart data. I added the line.destroy(); as suggested above which has done the trick

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
if(window.myLine){
 window.myLine.destroy();
}
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
  etc
  etc
```

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a way to do this without clearing the canvas or starting over, but you have to man handle the creation of the chart so that the data is in the same format for when you update.

Here is how I did it.

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    if (chartExists) {
        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            myNewChart.scale.xLabels[i]=dbLabels[i]; 
            myNewChart.datasets[0].bars[i].value=dbOnAir[i];
        }
        myNewChart.update();
      }else{
          console.log('chart doesnt exist');
          myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(dataNew);
          myNewChart.removeData();
          for (i=0;i<10;i++){
              myNewChart.addData([10],dbLabels[i]);
          }
          for (i=0;i<10;i++){      
              myNewChart.datasets[0].bars[i].value=dbOnAir[i];
          }
          myNewChart.update();
          chartExists=true;
        }
```

I basically scrap the data loaded in at creation, and then reform with the add data method. This means that I can then access all the points. Whenever I have tried to access the data structure that is created by the:

```
Chart(ctx).Bar(dataNew);
```

command, I can't access what I need. This means you can change all the data points, in the same way you created them, and also call update() without animating completely from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Chart JS 2.0

Just set
chart.data.labels = [];

For example:

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
       dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

$chart.data.labels = [];

$.each(res.grouped, function(i,o) {
   addData($chart, o.age, o.count);
});
$chart.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the chart object you need to save the instance in a variable.

```
var currentChart = new Chart(ctx, ...);
```

And before loading new data, you need to **destroy** it:

```
currentChart.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let a variable remember an instance of your chart.

```
             let yourChart = new Chart(ctxBar, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: datasets
                    },
                });
```

Secondly, the thing I mostly struggled with was getting the data structure in the right format before updating the chart.  So after looking at the  `data` key structure of chart js object:

```
  data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Net sales',
            data: data
        }, {
            label: 'Cost of goods sold',
            data: data
        }, {
            label: 'Gross margin',
            data: data
        }]
    }
```

Notice the `data` key value is an object consisting of two keys, `labels` and `datasets`.  `labels` key' value is an array, while `datasets` key' value is also an array with an object as value.

Therefore, to `remove` labels and datasets from a chart instance I used:

```
yourChart.data.labels = [];
yourChart.data.datasets = [{}];
yourChart.update();
```

To `add` labels and datasets to a chart instance I used:

```
yourChart.data.labels = ['label 1', 'label 2'];
yourChart.data.datasets = [{
                label: 'column lables',
                data: [450, 50],
                backgroundColor: ["#dc3545", "#ffb759"]
            }];
yourChart.update();
```

**Prepare server side**
The labels and datasets values can be prepared server side as follows (in my case php):

```php
$datajs = function ($data, $bg_colour) // function emulating chart js datasets key value structure
        {
            return [
                'data' => $data,
                'backgroundColor' => $bg_colour
            ];
        };
$datasets = [];
$labels = ['label 1', 'label 2'];
$datasets[] = $datajs([42,10], ["#dc3545", "#ffb759"]);
$datasets[] = $datajs([100,5], ["#dc3545", "#ffb759"]);
```

**To just replace data from data key value from datasets (I did not test this)**

```
yourChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data = [];
});
yourChart.update();
// if you have an array of arrays
let array = [[42,20],[58,68],[78,1]];
let length = yourChart.data.datasets.length;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const element = array[i];
    if (i < length) {
        yourChart.data.datasets[i].data = element;
    } else {
        yourChart.data.datasets[] = {data: element};
    }
}
yourChart.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me

```js
chart.config.data = [];
chart.update();
```