# Delete last chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The chart is drawn when I choose item from dropdown list. But when I choose another item chart have new data + last data.
For example:
Current data
[image: Current data]

Choosing new item
[image]

Have new data. But if to hold by the mouse above 1995 or 1997 we have:
[image]

It's last data. I tried chart.destroy() and chart.clear() and create new object with chart - doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788924/chartjs-bar-chart-showing-old-data-when-hovering), have you checked it?

Comment: It seems but not quite then

Comment: I found issue in that question. Thanks. But i want know why happen my situation)