# vue 3 chart.js data upadated from api but chart is not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

**vue 3 Chartjs is not rendering data dynamically from API**

currently, I am working on vue 3 and I am new. I added a chart from official chartjs documentation
I added the data field of the chart from API and it is working fine everything is rendering but whenever I try to update the same data field to another field it is not rendering the chart however Chart is receiving the data but not rendering

this is my JSON data from API

```
[{"ward":1,"maleCount":3,"femaleCount":1,"otherCount":1,"disableCount":0}, 
{"ward":2,"maleCount":0,"femaleCount":0,"otherCount":0,"disableCount":0}, 
{"ward":3,"maleCount":0,"femaleCount":0,"otherCount":0,"disableCount":0}, 
{"ward":4,"maleCount":0,"femaleCount":0,"otherCount":0,"disableCount":0},
```

this is how i call my api

```
 mounted() {
    this.getData();
  },

method:{
getData() {
      axios
        .get("api/v1/household/dashboard/getDetailByGharMuli")
        .then((res) => {
          this.data = res.data;
          this.wardCount = this.data.length;
          console.log(this.wardCount);
          let i = 0;
          let j = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            this.mdata.push(this.data[i].maleCount);
            this.Fdata.push(this.data[i].femaleCount);
            this.Odata.push(this.data[i].otherCount);
          }
          for (j = 1; j <= this.wardCount; j++) {
            this.llabels.push("Ward" + j);
          }
          this.barChart();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    },
barChart() {
      var Chart = require("chart.js");
      new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
          labels: this.llabels,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "पुरुष जनसंख्या",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 143, 251, 0.8)",
              data: this.mdata,
            },
           {
              label: "महिला जनसंख्या",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 227, 150, 0.8)",
              data: this.Fdata,
            },
            {
              label: "पअन्य जनसंख्या",
              backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 69, 96,0.8)",
              data: this.Odata,
            },
          ],
        },
      });
    },
}
```

I want to update data from the above JSON data according to Ward 1
but whenever I update data from API,
The chart is receiving data but not rendering it

```
setDataBywardID(data) {
      axios
        .get("api/v1/household/dashboard/getGenderCountAccordingToWard/" + data)
        .then((res) => {
          this.wardData = res.data;
          console.log(this.wardData);
          this.llabels = "total population";
          this.mdata = this.wardData.maleCount;
          console.log(this.mdata);
          this.Fdata = this.wardData.femaleCount;
          console.log(this.Fdata);
          this.Odata = this.wardData.otherCount;
          this.barChart();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you're trying to update a chart, you don't call `new Chart` every time.

You should save the chart when you create it (add `chart: null` to `data`), then you could check if it exists when calling your `barChart` function.

Have a read of [Updating Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)

Something like this:

```
barChart() {
    var Chart = require("chart.js");
    var options = {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: this.llabels,
            datasets: [
            {
                label: "पुरुष जनसंख्या",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 143, 251, 0.8)",
                data: this.mdata,
            },
            {
                label: "महिला जनसंख्या",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 227, 150, 0.8)",
                data: this.Fdata,
            },
            {
                label: "पअन्य जनसंख्या",
                backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 69, 96,0.8)",
                data: this.Odata,
            }]
        }
    };

    if(!chart)
        this.chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), options);
    else
    {
        this.chart.options = options;
        this.chart.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanku <3 it worked fine for me but after updating the data chart is showing previous data on hover
i tried using this.chart.destroy() but i didnt work for me. can you please help me out

Comment: Does this help? [Chartjs Bar Chart showing old data when hovering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42788924/3688864)

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and provide a fiddle then