# Why refreshing data using horizontalBar report of Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts

I use horizontalBar report of Chart.js( Version: 2.7.2 ) in my application and I have a problem
that refreshing data with jquery with new parameters (so different data are shown) and hovering mouse over report I see old report chart.

Googling I found this branch 
[Destroy chart.js bar graph to redraw other graph in same <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056555/destroy-chart-js-bar-graph-to-redraw-other-graph-in-same-canvas)
and tried 3 ways to fix this error like:

```
                var barOptions= {
                    legend: { display: false },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Quizzes rating'
                    }
                };


/*
                // Fixing way # 1 BLOCK START
                $("#div_canvasQuizzesRating").remove();     // If to uncomment this block I got error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
                $("#div_canvasQuizzesRating").append('<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">\n' +
                    '                    <div class="panel panel-default">\n' +
                    '                        <div class="panel-body">\n' +
                    '                            <p class=" text-muted small">\n' +
                    '                                Any quiz can be rated from 1 till 5.\n' +
                    '                            </p>\n' +
                    '                            <canvas id="canvasQuizzesRating" width="800" height="450"></canvas>\n' +
                    '                        </div>\n' +
                    '                    </div>\n' +
                    '                </div>');

                // Fixing way # 1 BLOCK END
*/

                var grapharea = document.getElementById("canvasQuizzesRating").getContext("2d");


/*
                // Fixing way # 2 BLOCK START  // If to uncomment this block I DO NOT got error, but hovering mouse I have prior chart data visible
                var chartObject = new Chart(grapharea, { type: 'canvasQuizzesRating', data: valuesArray, options: barOptions });
                chartObject.destroy();
                // Fixing way # 2 BLOCK END
*/

                // $("canvas#chartreport").remove();

                var chartObject= new Chart(grapharea, {
                    type: 'horizontalBar',     // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html
                    data: {
                        labels: labelsArray,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "Average rating mark",
                                backgroundColor: this_chartBackgroundColors,
                                // backgroundColor: ["#005500", "#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#ff063c", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#ffff00", "#0000ff", "#fb6bff", "#55ffff", "#c6c7ff", "#aaff7f", "#a5aaff", "#fffda6", "#707070", "#c45850", "#dfdf00" ],
                                data: valuesArray
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    options: barOptions

                });

                // // Fixing way # 3 BLOCK START // If to uncomment this block I DO NOT got error, but hovering mouse I have prior chart data visible
                // chartObject.update();
                // // Fixing way # 3 BLOCK END
```

The code above has 3 blocks when I tried to fix this error:
Fixing way # 1(2,3) BLOCK START
But I failed with all of them.

You can look at it by link http://votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/report_quizzes_rating
(there would be login page with creditials provided).
Opening this page results without filters would be shown.
Then please select 1 category( 
like "History" ) and click "Report" and hove mouse over the report - you will see the problem.

How to fix this problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give global scope to the variable and assign your div to the variable. like below

```
window.chartObject= new Chart(grapharea, {
                    type: 'horizontalBar',     // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html
                    data: {
                        labels: labelsArray,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "Average rating mark",
                                backgroundColor: this_chartBackgroundColors,
                                // backgroundColor: ["#005500", "#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#ff063c", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#ffff00", "#0000ff", "#fb6bff", "#55ffff", "#c6c7ff", "#aaff7f", "#a5aaff", "#fffda6", "#707070", "#c45850", "#dfdf00" ],
                                data: valuesArray
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    options: barOptions

                });
```

Append below lines above global scope: This will check whether the chart is created or not. If yes it will destroy and redraw the chart

```
    //clear chart
    if (window.chartObject!= undefined)
        window.chartObject.destroy();
```

So final code will be :

```
     if (window.chartObject!= undefined)
                window.chartObject.destroy();


window.chartObject= new Chart(grapharea, {
                    type: 'horizontalBar',     // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html
                    data: {
                        labels: labelsArray,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "Average rating mark",
                                backgroundColor: this_chartBackgroundColors,
                                // backgroundColor: ["#005500", "#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#ff063c", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#ffff00", "#0000ff", "#fb6bff", "#55ffff", "#c6c7ff", "#aaff7f", "#a5aaff", "#fffda6", "#707070", "#c45850", "#dfdf00" ],
                                data: valuesArray
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    options: barOptions

                });
```