# Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '3' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to update Bar chart when a dropdown values getting change on a field. I tried all the answers here [Destroy chart.js bar graph to redraw other graph in same <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056555/destroy-chart-js-bar-graph-to-redraw-other-graph-in-same-canvas), but no luck. Can you please help me?

Below is the code that I have written to remove canvas element and recreate it

html

```
  <div class="p-grid">
            <div class="p-col-12" id="chart-bar">
                <canvas id="myBarChart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
```

TS

```
const ctx: any = document.getElementById('myBarChart')
            ctx.remove();
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", "myBarChart");
            canvas.setAttribute('width','1007');  
            canvas.setAttribute('height','503');  
            canvas.setAttribute('style','display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 64vh; width: 35vw;');  
            const element = document.getElementById("chart-bar");
            element.appendChild(canvas);
            
            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData.value,
                options: chartOptions,
            })
```

Tried `destroy()` option as below. It didn't work

```
const chart = ref(null)

 if(chart.value){
                chart.value.destroy()
            }

            const ctx: any = document.getElementById('myBarChart')

           chart.value =  new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData.value,
                options: chartOptions,
            })
```

I can see it's there in the DOM, but graph is not displaying

[image]

Comment: _"I tried all the answers [here], but no luck."_ - what are we supposed to do with that? We can't tell if you did anything _wrong_, if you don't show us what exactly you did.

Comment: I have added my code above that what I am trying now. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here that I cannot see my graph there?

Comment: You did not actually do, what the answers to that other question suggested.

Comment: I did. I tried destroy as above. It didn't work. So I tried to remove canvas and create it back

Comment: Of course that does not work - you are trying to create a _new_ `Chart` instance now (to then destroy that again) - but the error you are trying solve, prevented you from creating a new instance in the first place. You need to store the result of `new Chart(...)` into a variable, and then call the `destroy` method on that, before you try to create a new instance.

Comment: I updated it now. Is that the correct way? Still I am getting error though

Comment: No, you are _still_ trying to create a new instance, at a point where you currently _can't_ create a new one. You need to store the _actual_ Chart instance into a variable, not create a second one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242330/discussion-between-purni-and-cbroe).

Comment: Can you show me the steps please? I want to create a new instance again after destroy

Comment: Are you actually following up with the chat now, or ...?

Comment: Yes I do follow the chat

Comment: So where exactly did you place `const chart = ref(null)` - not just before the `if`, as shown? You can't set it to null _every_ time, that needs to happen only once before the whole process starts.

Comment: Yes that's how I have defined. I've declared this once as a global variable outside this function.

Answer (score 0):

Start by declaring a global variable to hold the chart, assigning the variable a null value:

```
let myChart = null;
```

Then execute your function/logic that draws the chart for the first time, saving the chart to the `myChart` variable:

```
function functionToDrawChart(params){
    ...
    // other code for your function
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

And when you want to update the chart, where you are supposed to destroy the chart, first check that `myChart` is not null, if it isn't, destroy the chart

```
if(myChart != null){
    myChart.destroy();
};

functionToDrawChart(params);
```

This fixed the issue for me when I was trying to change the data used for my bar chart. I guess one could use the `update` method on the `chart` object, but I haven't explored that.

Hope this is of help.

Cheers!!

[reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeStwBfNz0w)

Answer (score -1):

Because you have removed that and after create new now you have to add again.

```
 ctx = document.getElementById('myBarChart');
     new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: chartData.value,
                    options: chartOptions,
                })
```