# How to reuse a Chart.js chart in Blazor wasm?

Tags: chart.js, blazor-webassembly

How to reuse a Chart.js chart in Blazor wasm? I got the error message to destroy the canvas before reuseing. I read this topic: [Destroy chart.js bar graph to redraw other graph in same <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056555/destroy-chart-js-bar-graph-to-redraw-other-graph-in-same-canvas)
But none of these answers solved my problem. This is my method to invoke the JavaScript of Chart.js

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", Id, config);

window.setup = (id, config) => {
    var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

How can I implement a working .destroy() call in the method, or how can I update the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
window.setup = (id, config) => {

    var myChart = Chart.getChart(id);

    if (myChart != undefined) {
        myChart.destroy();
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, config);

    console.log(config);
}
```

(First it was not working for reasons of the browsers cache)