# How to dynamically render new list of charts based on a dropdown filter?

Tags: javascript, laravel, canvas, chart.js, laravel-livewire

I am not trying to refresh the existing charts on the blade. Here's the scenario, each module has a list of questions, options and answers (option selected by the user). I have a dropdown to filter the questions by module.

I managed to dynamically generate the charts for the first module on load, but when I change to module 2, chartData is updated and passed back to the script via emit but I am unable to update the blade. The error I got is, **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
at 4:2072:66** from **const ctx = document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext('2d');**.

I have also referred to this [Destroy chart.js bar graph to redraw other graph in same <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056555/destroy-chart-js-bar-graph-to-redraw-other-graph-in-same-canvas) , any help is appreciated.

Livewire Component

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->modules = $this->session->course->modules->where('status', 'PUBLISHED');
    $this->selectedModule = $this->modules->first()->id;

    $this->GetQuestions();
    $this->preparePieChartData();
}

public function preparePieChartData()
{
    $singleChoiceQuestions = $this->questions->where('type', 'single_choice');

    $data = [];

    foreach ($singleChoiceQuestions as $question) {
        if ($question->answers->count() > 0) {
            $options = $question->options;

            $questionData = [
                'question' => $question->question_text,
                'options' => [],
            ];

            foreach ($options as $option) {
                $count = $question->answers
                    ->where('option_uuid', $option->uuid)
                    ->where('session_id', $this->session->id)
                    ->count();

                $questionData['options'][] = [
                    'option' => $option->option_text,
                    'count' => $count,
                ];
            }

            $data[] = $questionData;
        }
    }


    $this->chartData = $data;
    
    $this->emitSelf('chartDataUpdated', $data);
}

public function updatedSelectedModule()
{
    $this->GetQuestions();
    $this->preparePieChartData();
}
```

On the blade,

```
<select class="form-control-sm form-control" wire:model="selectedModule">
    @foreach($modules as $module)
        <option value="{{ $module->id }}">{{ $module->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

@foreach($questions as $question)
    if ($question->type == 'single_choice')
        <canvas id="pieChart{{ $loop->index }}" style="max-height: 300px; display: block;"></canvas>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

At the end of blade the script

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        const chartInstances = [];

        function GenerateCharts(chartData) {
            console.log('drawing charts...');

            chartData.forEach((chart, index) => {
                console.log(index);
                console.log(chart);

                const config = {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: {
                        labels: chart.options.map(option => option.option),
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Total',
                            data: chart.options.map(option => option.count),
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        plugins: {}
                    },
                }

                const canvasId = `pieChart${index}`;

                if (chartInstances[canvasId]) {
                    chartInstances[canvasId].destroy();
                    delete chartInstances[canvasId];
                }

                const ctx = document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext('2d');

                chartInstances[canvasId] = new Chart(ctx, config);
            });
        }

        GenerateCharts(@js($chartData));

        @this.on('chartDataUpdated', (data) => {
            GenerateCharts(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use events to re-call the script. For example, you could catch which field has been updated, using the [`updated`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks#class-hooks) method:

```php
public function updated($field, $value) 
{
    // Validate which field should trigger a chart update. If all updates should, no if statement is needed.
    if ($field === 'questions') {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('update-chart');
    }
}
```

Then in the frontend, you can catch it:

```js
window.addEventListener('update-chart', () => {
    // Tear down current chart and initialize new chart
});
```

Comment: An alternate to this would just use livewire and setup polling

Comment: I have tried using dispatch, does not work. I have also updated the way I initialise the script