# Chartjs 2.x - Dataset color changing when redrawing chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-canvas, chart.js

here's the issue: I'm drawing a chart using external data (a .txt file that the user upload with datasets information). But if the user mistakenly upload the wrong file, he should be able to upload another file, thus redrawing the charts.

Here's what happen with the chart rendering when I upload multiple files, one after another:

Example of what they looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqPjy.jpg

Each time a draw the chart again, the background color gets darker. Every time a user upload a file I do the following:

1. do a `chart.destroy()` and a `chart.clear()`
2. Remove used canvas and use a new one for the new chart

Is this a known issue? Anyone have any clue of what might be happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815851/how-to-clear-a-chart-from-a-canvas-so-that-hover-events-cannot-be-triggered
here is someone got problem i was thinking maybe same as yours,
he just delete the canvas and replace a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of things regarding cleaning the canvas and the chart instances, but ended up taking another approach (and probably a better one). Instead of removing the chart (and its canvas) and creating a new one, I updated the chart's data (replacing the old dataset for the new one).

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.chartsList.length; i++) {
  var chart          = $scope.chartsList[i];
  var firstDataSet   = $scope.formattedData[i];
  var secondDataSet  = $scope.formattedData[i + 15];                

  for(var j = 0; j < 51; j++) {
    chart.config.data.datasets[0].data = firstDataSet;
    chart.config.data.datasets[1].data = secondDataSet;

    chart.update();
  }
```

Done!