# Redraw Chart.js with PHP JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I created a page where there the user selects a business and the page throws a barchart. The problem is that, the first time the use selects a business, the page shows the barchart correctly, but the second time the user selects a business, the page throw two charts with the past and new information. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Estadisticas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <select id="mySelect"></select>

    <p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <div id="graph-container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var values = ["uno","dos","tres","cuatro","cinco"]
    var option = '';
    for (var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
       option += '<option value="'+ values[i] + '">' + numbers[i] + '</option>';
    }
    $('#mySelect').append(option);
    */

    $.ajax({
        url: "xx",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            var values = [];
            var business = [];
            var option = '';
            for (var i in data) {
                values.push(data[i].values);
                business.push(data[i].Business);
                option += '<option value="' + values[i] + '">' + business[i] + '</option>';
            }

            $('#mySelect').append(option);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    function getData(dato) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "zx",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var date = [];
                var views = [];

                for (var i in data) {
                    date.push("Date " + data[i].Date);
                    views.push(data[i].Views);
                }

                var chartdata = {
                    labels: date,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Date',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(231,76,60 ,1)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(231,76,60 ,1)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(52,152,219 ,1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(52,152,219 ,1)',
                        data: views
                    }]
                };
                var ctx = $("#myChart");

                var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: chartdata
                });
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    }
    $('#mySelect').change(function() {
        console.log($(this).find(':selected').text());
        console.log($(this).find(':selected').val());
        getData($(this).find(':selected').val());
    });
});
```

My webservices work, the only problem is at the moment the user selects another business, the page throws two charts with the past and new information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chart.js replace all data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768583/chart-js-replace-all-data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destroy chart.js bar graph to redraw other graph in same <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056555/destroy-chart-js-bar-graph-to-redraw-other-graph-in-same-canvas)

Comment: i will check those links, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new dataset and push into the chart

Comment: Ooh I get it, I will try it and let you you know if it works :)