# Chart.js load new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

I am trying to load new data (to hide specific graph), I tried `destroy()` function [**like here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785713/chart-js-load-totally-new-data) but it's not working, I did't know what I am missing.

I want to load one data (of two) but I want to select which one to visible.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="linechart"></canvas>
<div>
  <a id="current">Current</a>
  <a id="forecast">Forecast</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('linechart');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var current = [800, 1350, 1400, 1600, 2600, 3100];
    var forecast = [400, 1050, 1200, 1300, 1800, 2400];
    var data = {
      labels: ["2", "4", "8", "12", "16", "20"],
      pointDotRadius: 0,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth : 0,
      pointHitRadius: 0,
      datasets: [
      {
        label: "current",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
        strokeColor: "#7bc775",
        pointColor: "#7bc775",
        data: current,
      },
      {
        label: "forecast",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
        strokeColor: "#fed477",
        pointColor: "#fed477",
        data: forecast,
      }]
    };
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data
    });
    var step  = 800;
    var max   = 3200;
    var start = 0;
    window.myObjBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
      scaleOverride: true,
      scaleSteps: Math.ceil((max-start)/step),
      scaleStepWidth: step,
      scaleStartValue: start,
      responsive : true
    });
    $('#current').click(function(){
      current = [];
      if(myLineChart!== null){
        myLineChart.destroy();
        myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: data
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/3563ko2t/)**

Comment: Did you actually try `.distroy()`, as you mentioned in your question, instead of `.destroy()` ? -- **Edit :** Nevermind, I just saw your fiddle

Comment: Sorry, that was typo. I actually use destroy(), you can check code on fiddle too.

Comment: You might find [chartNew.js](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js) easier to work with -- it's just like chart.js except that the api works as documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem using an up to date version of Charts.js

Using destroy and storing your datas in an array. When you click on the control, it destroys the chart and rebuild a new one with the selected data

```
var mychart = new Chart(ctx,config);
$('.selector').click(function(){
 data.datasets = [datasets[$(this).data('index')]];
 if(mychart!== null){
      mychart.destroy();
      mychart = new Chart(ctx, config);
 }
 });
```

See the updated fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/3563ko2t/6/

Comment: this what I needed but I want both line (at first) and I want to hide top box with label

Comment: so just replace var currentData = [datasets[0]]; by var currentData = datasets;

Comment: what about start, max and step ?

Comment: These options can be specified within the config variable , see http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-common-configuration for more details.