# how to reset the graph/chart after zoomin, pan using chartjs

Tags: php, html, chart.js

I recently added zoom-in and pan functionality to my line chart. Now i want to add a reset button or something like that when pressed graph come back to normal position/shape. Currently i am drawing it for dynamic data which get updated every10 seconds.

ThankYou in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Try [chartjs-plugin-zoom](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom)

First, get the Chart.js instance, and then you can just call the `resetZoom` function of the instance to reset the zooming and panning.

```
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);

...

function resetZoom() {
  window.myLine.resetZoom();
}

...

<button onclick="resetZoom()">Reset Zoom</button>
```

The `chart.js` version I'm using is `2.9.3` and `chartjs-plugin-zoom` version `0.7.7`

See examples:

- [chartjs-plugin-zoom samples](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/blob/master/samples/zoom-time.html)
- [chartjs zoom and pan on codepen](https://codepen.io/thinkerBell/pen/ZNNwWV)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:

Try any of these:

**1.  .clear()**

**2. .destroy()**

```
myLineChart.destroy();
```

Then re-initialize the chart:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChartLine").getContext("2d");
myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

3. delete the  element and then reappending a new  to the parent container

   `var resetCanvas = function () {`

   ```
      $('#results-graph').remove(); // this is my <canvas> element

      $('#graph-container').append('<canvas id="results-graph"><canvas>');

     canvas = document.querySelector('#results-graph'); 

     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

     ctx.canvas.width = $('#graph').width(); // resize to parent width

     ctx.canvas.height = $('#graph').height(); // resize to parent height

     var x = canvas.width/2;
     var y = canvas.height/2;
     ctx.font = '10pt Verdana';
     ctx.textAlign = 'center';
     ctx.fillText('This text is centered on the canvas', x, y);
   };`
   ```
4. **.update( )**

Calling update() on your Chart instance will re-render the chart with any updated values, allowing you to edit the value of multiple existing points, then render those in one animated render loop.

Also refer:

[How to clear a chart from a canvas so that hover events cannot be triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815851/how-to-clear-a-chart-from-a-canvas-so-that-hover-events-cannot-be-triggered/30468773#30468773)

[chart.js load totally new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785713/chart-js-load-totally-new-data)