# How to update the data in an ng2-chartjs2 chart in Angular 2 and Node JS

Tags: node.js, charts, typescript, angular

I am using NodeJS, Angular2, and the ng2-chartjs2. Below I listed the relevant parts of my code that is rendering charts. The data is loaded into this.data from an API using a fixed date range. I would like to allow the user to select a date range and then update the chart. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354163/dynamically-update-values-of-a-chartjs-chart) I know that you can call update() on the chart object to update the data in it, but I don't know how to get a hold of the chart object, since the component code never actually has a reference to it - it's done automagically when the template is rendered. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-chartjs2/blob/master/components/chart.component.ts) (line 13) I see that the author intended to make the object available. I contacted the author but haven't received a response yet and need to get moving. I have learned a lot about Angular2 but am no expert yet, so perhaps a deeper understanding of Angular2 makes this obvious. How can I either get access to the object to call update() on it, or do it some other clean way?

The template contains

```
    <chart [options]="simple.options"></chart>
```

and the component typescript code contains

```
import { ChartComponent } from 'ng2-chartjs2';
...

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'client/components/home/home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['client/components/home/home.component.css'],
    directives: [DashboardLayoutComponent, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ChartComponent],
    pipes: [AddCommasPipe],
})

...

setCurrentSimpleChart = (simpleType: number): void => {
    this.simple.options = {
        type: 'line',
        options: this.globalOptions,
        data: {
            labels: this.data[simpleType].labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: this.titles[simpleType],
                data: this.data[simpleType].data,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
        },
    };

    ...
}
```

Update: In case this helps anyone: I actually have two different charts on the page, so I googled around based on the accepted answer and found ViewChildren, and mapped them to different variables so I can update them both separately, with

```
[this.simpleChart, this.liftChart] = this.chartComponents.toArray().map(component => component.chart);
```

(Note also that this was using an rc of angular2 - since then directives, etc have been moved out of the components themselves.)

Comment: Can you paste your full working code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold reference to component by using `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild(ChartComponent) chartComp;
```

And then you can get `chart` object:

```
let chart = this.chartComp.chart;
```

Here is the **[corresponding plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hyRL43StbeQUps78b56m?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you. In case this helps anyone: I actually have two different charts on the page, so I googled around based on your answer and found ViewChildren, and mapped them to different variables so I can update them both separately, with [this.simpleChart, this.liftChart] = this.chartComponents.toArray().map((component) => component.chart);

Comment: @DovevHefetz do you mind updating your question with your mappings to different variables? This will be helpful to others including me.