# Updating a chart from chart.js in vue

Tags: jquery, vue.js, chart.js

I have a function in my vue applications that creates a chart.This is the chart function:

```
startChart: function (canvas, type) {

    // init chart.js
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: this.getAnalyticList[this.getRowIndex].chartNames,
            datasets: [{
                data: this.getAnalyticList[this.getRowIndex].chartData,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
                    'red',
                    'yellow',
                    'blue',
                    'green',
                    'orange',
                    'teal',
                    'violet',
                    'pink',
                    'purple'
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            defaultFontColor: '#ffffff',

        }
    })
}
```

and i then started it in the vue mounted hook using this line

```
this.startChart(this.$refs.canvas, 'Doughnut');
```

What i want to do is take the row index of a table loaded above the chart and that would then be passed into the getAnalyticList value that loads the charts so i can grab different arrays from the same list. I was working on creating an update function i got off this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/red_stapler/u5aanta8/1/) from this [stack article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354163/dynamically-update-values-of-a-chartjs-chart). I've been trying to adapt the function he created into vue but am having no luck here is the function:

```
changeData: function () {
            var myChart = Chart.doughnut(this.$refs.canvas, {
                data: data,
            });
            myChart.data.datasets.data = this.getAnalyticList[this.getRowIndex].chartData;
            myChart.data.labels = this.getAnalyticList[this.getRowIndex].chartNames;
            myChart.update();
        }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You may be interested in [vue-chartjs](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs). It's well tested and maintained, so you shouldn't have to do the integration yourself.

Comment: unfortunately its not possible for this current project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only problem with your code is that you're not updating the dataset correctly.
With `myChart.data.datasets.data = ...` your adding data to datasets object - it should be `myChart.data.datasets[0].data = ...`.

I've also added the chart object to Vue.js model in `startChart` with-out reactivity because it needs to be updated manually. Just don't add it to data hook. So you can reference the chart with `this.myChart` in your updating method.

I've renamed `getRowIndex` in the demo because `rowIndex` is more readable - you could do the same with the `getAnalyticsLists`. I would name it with get-prefix if it's a method that is getting something.

Scroll down in the demo to toggle the data with the next button. That button increments `rowIndex` and rolls over at the end.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/qqwc478b/).

```js
const chartComponent = {
  data() {
      return {
        //myChart: undefined, // don't add chart here -> reactivity could be a problem
        getAnalyticList: [{
          chartNames: [
            'Red',
            'Yellow',
            'Blue'
          ],
          chartData: [10, 20, 30]
        },
        {
          chartNames: [
            'Red',
            'Yellow',
            'Blue'
          ],
          chartData: [40, 10, 20]
        }
        ],
        rowIndex: 0
      }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
    <button @click="incRow">next</button>
    {{rowIndex}}
    </div>
  `,
    methods: {
      startChart: function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myDoughnut = this.myChart =  new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'doughnut',
          data: {
            labels: this.getAnalyticList[this.rowIndex].chartNames,
            datasets: [{
              data: this.getAnalyticList[this.rowIndex].chartData,
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
                'red',
                'yellow',
                'blue',
                'green',
                'orange',
                'teal',
                'violet',
                'pink',
                'purple'
              ]
            }]
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            defaultFontColor: '#ffffff',
      
          }
        })
      },
      incRow () {
       if (this.rowIndex < this.getAnalyticList.length - 1) {
         this.rowIndex++;
        }
        else {
         this.rowIndex = 0;
        }
        this.changeData()
      },
      changeData () {
       this.myChart.data.datasets[0].data =
         this.getAnalyticList[this.rowIndex].chartData;
        this.myChart.data.labels = this.getAnalyticList[this.rowIndex].chartNames;
        this.myChart.update();
        console.log('changed', this.myChart.data)
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log('started')
      this.startChart();
    }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    chart: chartComponent
  }
})
```

```css
div {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <chart></chart>
</div>
```