# How to implement dynamic data on chartjs?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, chart.js

I need your help to learn how to dynamically implement data from a json file to Chartjs. The fields that I need to fill dynamically are `labels` and `data`.

```
JSON File <<<

[
   {
      "EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID":1,
      "EFICAZ_PERCENTS":99
   },
   {
      "EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID":2,
      "EFICAZ_PERCENTS":99
   },
   {
      "EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID":3,
      "EFICAZ_PERCENTS":99
   }
]


CHARTJS <<<

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: [???],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [???],
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

Comment: You need to get 2 arrays from your json:  
1) Array of labels  
2) Array of values  
Then you've to set that arrays as data.labels and data.datasets.data.  

If it's not initial values of your charts you have to update your charts with update() method called to your chart's instance.

Comment: And btw, your question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354163/dynamically-update-values-of-a-chartjs-chart)

Comment: @Brissy like this? labels: ArrayLabel data: ArrayData?

Answer (score 1):

I have used `$.ajax()` to fetch JSON data, and save the data in two arrays, then you can use these arrays for your chart label and data. Hope this helps!

```
 var lbl = [];
    var dta = [];

    $.ajax({
      url: "test.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, field){
             lbl.push(field.EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID
    );
               dta.push(field.EFICAZ_PERCENTS);

           });
      }
    });


     $.getJSON("test.json", function(result){
           $.each(result, function(i, field){
             lbl.push(field.EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID
    );
               dta.push(field.EFICAZ_PERCENTS);

           });
        });


    var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');



    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: lbl,
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: dta,
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  
  var chartData = [
   {
      "EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID":1,
      "EFICAZ_PERCENTS":21
   },
   {
      "EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID":2,
      "EFICAZ_PERCENTS":55
   },
   {
      "EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID":3,
      "EFICAZ_PERCENTS":32
   }
]
 
 var labels = [];
 var values = [];
 chartData.forEach(function(el,key){
  labels.push(el.EFICAZ_TAB_ITEM_ID);
  values.push(el.EFICAZ_PERCENTS);
})
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: values,
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```