# Click on chartjs pie slice to hide the slice

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to get chartjs to hide pie slices on click; the same behavior seen when clicking on the legend.

Here is the code I'm using - I commented out the code that actually removes the data from the chart since it doesn't re-render the pie chart correctly.

```js
const values = [50, 55, 60, 33];
const data = {
  labels: ["India", "China", "US", "Canada"],
  datasets: [{
    data: values,
    backgroundColor: [
      "#4b77a9",
      "#5f255f",
      "#d21243",
      "#B27200"
    ],
    borderColor: "#fff"
  }]
};

const options = {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    position: 'bottom'
  },
  animation: false,
  onClick: handleClick,
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      formatter: (value = 0, ctxx) => {
        const sum = values.reduce((acc, val = 0) => (acc + val), 0);
        return `${(value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2)}%`;
      },
      color: '#fff',
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data,
  options: options
});

function handleClick(e, slice) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const legend = myChart.legend.legendItems;
    if (slice && slice[0]) {
      // get clicked on slice index
      const sliceIndex = slice[0]._index;
      // Removing the data "really" messes up the chart
      // myChart.data.labels.splice(sliceIndex, 1);
      // myChart.data.datasets[0].data.splice(sliceIndex, 1);
      legend[sliceIndex].hidden = true;
      chart.update();
    }
    const visibleSlices = legend.filter(l => !l.hidden);
    console.log('visible slices', visibleSlices);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.4.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="pie-chart"></canvas>
```

It *seems* like setting the hidden flag then updating the chart should work because that's what the plugin is doing: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/plugins/plugin.legend.js#L20-L30.

Comment: When i look about you problem. I found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354163/dynamically-update-values-of-a-chartjs-chart

Comment: That's an example of updating/changing the data, I only want to toggle the view of the data - hiding a slice on click.

Comment: You just have a typo error, `chart` needs to be `myChart`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below is hiding a slice by the index

```
myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[sliceIndex].hidden = true
```

```js
const values = [50, 55, 60, 33];
const data = {
  labels: ["India", "China", "US", "Canada"],
  datasets: [{
    data: values,
    backgroundColor: [
      "#4b77a9",
      "#5f255f",
      "#d21243",
      "#B27200"
    ],
    borderColor: "#fff"
  }]
};

const options = {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    position: 'bottom'
  },
  animation: false,
  onClick: handleClick,
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      formatter: (value = 0, ctxx) => {
        const sum = values.reduce((acc, val = 0) => (acc + val), 0);
        return `${(value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2)}%`;
      },
      color: '#fff',
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data,
  options: options
});

function handleClick(e, slice) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const legend = myChart.legend.legendItems;
    if (slice && slice[0]) {
      const sliceIndex = slice[0]._index;

      myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[sliceIndex].hidden = true

      myChart.update();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.4.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="pie-chart"></canvas>
```