# I need to increase data in a bar chart by one with a button click

Tags: javascript, chart.js

As it says on a title, I need to increase data in a chart by one by click of a button. There are three bars/datasets, each with own button, plus a reset button. I've tried using the example in chart.js documentation, but don't know where to go from here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 500px;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Autojen lukumäärä</h2>
    <button onclick="addCar">Ford</button>
    <button onclick="addCar">Opel</button>
    <button onclick="addCar">Toyota</button>
    <button onclick="nollaa">Nollaa</button>
    <canvas id="viivaTaulukko" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="autolaskuri.js"></script>
    <p id="Ford"></p>
    <p id="Opel"></p>
    <p id="Toyota"></p>
    <p id="Nollaa"></p>

    <script>
        function addCar(){
            barChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] += 1;
            barChart.update();
        }

        function nollaa(){
            barChart.reset();
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const CHART = document.getElementById("viivaTaulukko");
let barChart = new Chart(CHART, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Ford", "Opel", "Toyota"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Autojen lukumäärät",
                data: [0,0,0],
                backgroundColor: ["#0EBFE9", "#8E388E", "#70DBDB"]

            }
            
        ]
    },
    options:{
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354163/dynamically-update-values-of-a-chartjs-chart) answer

Comment: please can you put a working example so that anyone can help you ?

Comment: The code works. Ihave the bars and the buttons. BUt the buttons don't do anything/update data. It's in the code what I tried to do.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed parantheses in your `onclick` declarations. Your button definitions should look like this to make the fundtion to be called

```
<button onclick="addCar()">Ford</button>
<button onclick="addCar()">Opel</button>
<button onclick="addCar()">Toyota</button>
<button onclick="nollaa()">Nollaa</button>
```

By making additional changes to the `addCar` function, you can specify which data set should be updated.
You just need to update the part in your HTML file, for example like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 500px;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Autojen lukumäärä</h2>
    <button onclick="addCar(0)">Ford</button>
    <button onclick="addCar(1)">Opel</button>
    <button onclick="addCar(2)">Toyota</button>
    <button onclick="nollaa()">Nollaa</button>
    <canvas id="viivaTaulukko" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="autolaskuri.js"></script>
    <p id="Ford"></p>
    <p id="Opel"></p>
    <p id="Toyota"></p>
    <p id="Nollaa"></p>

    <script>
        function addCar(columnNumber){
            barChart.data.datasets[0].data[columnNumber] += 1;
            barChart.update();
        }

        function nollaa(){
            barChart.reset();
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've found another issue wthat might affect the function responsible for reseting the chart. Once the `Nollaa` button will be clicked, the diagram will be cleared, but clicking on any car will bring back the whole diagram back. So before reseting the display, you might need to clear all of your data sets

```
function nollaa(){
    let colsCount = barChart.data.datasets[0].data.length;
    for (let colNo = 0; colNo < colsCount; colNo++) {
        barChart.data.datasets[0].data[colNo] = 0;
    }
    barChart.reset();
}
```

Here you can find some working example https://jsfiddle.net/bnvL0eu1/4/.

Also for the future, it will be much easier to others to help you, if your HTML/JS/CSS will be embedded through the JSFiddle ([How do I include code for JSFiddle?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358212/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle)).

Comment: You probably want to pass which set you are updating to the addCar function as well
`<button onclick="addCar(0)">Ford</button><button onclick="addCar(1)">Opel</button><button onclick="addCar(2)">Toyota</button>` Then your function would need to be something like ` function addCar(set){
            barChart.data.datasets[0].data[set] += 1;
            barChart.update();
        }`